# How to return a incremental group number per group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I would like create a data query in SQL to incrementally number groups of rows, grouped on a common datetime and keep the "group numbers" incrementing on the next datetime and so on. These "group numbers" must not reset for each group as I have seen when using the partition by statement. Here is my sample data:

```
ts_DateTime          |ID   |Value|RowFilter|RequiredResult
--------------------------
2013/01/09 09:23:16  |8009 |0    |1        |1
2013/01/09 09:23:16  |8010 |0    |2        |1
2013/01/09 09:23:16  |8026 |0    |3        |1

2013/01/09 09:23:22  |8026 |0    |1        |2

2013/01/09 09:23:28  |8009 |0    |1        |3
2013/01/09 09:23:28  |8010 |0    |2        |3
2013/01/09 09:23:28  |8026 |0    |3        |3

2013/01/09 09:27:03  |8009 |0    |1        |4
2013/01/09 09:27:03  |8010 |0    |2        |4
2013/01/09 09:27:03  |8026 |0    |3        |4

2013/01/09 09:27:09  |8009 |0    |1        |5
2013/01/09 09:27:09  |8010 |0    |2        |5
2013/01/09 09:27:09  |8026 |0    |3        |5

2013/01/09 09:27:15  |8009 |0    |1        |6
2013/01/09 09:27:15  |8010 |0    |2        |6
2013/01/09 09:27:15  |8026 |0    |3        |6
```

The query I am using to get these results is :

```
select hl.ts_DateTime,  hl.Tagname as [ID],  hl.TagValue as [Value],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hl.ts_datetime ORDER BY hl.tagname) AS RowFilter
from Table1 hl
```

So basically, looking at the RowFilter column, I am getting a unique ROW number per `ts_DateTime` partition. What I actually need is that for each `ts_DateTime` partition the RowFilter column should look like the Required result column.

Comment: What kind of SQL?  This sort of thing is database-dependent.

Comment: I was stuck with the same problem and just couldn't see the solution. The key here is to take the `PARTITION BY` clause of the first window function and make it the `ORDER BY` clause of the second window function (which is unpartitioned).

Comment: I find it ironic that the "wrong result" you're getting is actually what I need. :) Thanks for posting the code.

Comment: Me too - You're 'wrong result' just solved my problem - Thanks and upvoted!

Answer (score 134):

you shouldn't be using `ROW_NUMBER()`,

- use `DENSE_RANK()` instead
- remove `PARTITION BY`

query,

```
SELECT hl.ts_DateTime,  
       hl.Tagname as [ID],  
       hl.TagValue as [Value],
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ts_datetime) AS RowFilter
FROM   Table1 hl 
ORDER  BY RowFilter
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a333f/7)

Comment: I've edited John Woo's answer. It does not enumerate RowFilter properly. Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1e62d/15

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hl.id ORDER BY hl.ts_DateTime) AS RowFilter
```

Answer (score 1):

-- Here Is my answer Mr.Chris Ballance :

```
select 
   hl.ts_DateTime,  hl.Tagname as [ID],  hl.TagValue as [Value],
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY hl.ts_datetime ORDER BY hl.tagname) AS RowFilter,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY hl.ts_datetime ORDER BY hl.Tagname) AS RequiredResult
from Table1 h1
```

--Try this It Is worked for me...

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! If you are posting something akin to 'code' you may want to try and use the curly braces sign in the editor window? That will make it much clearer what SQL statement you suggested?