# Limit certain attribute on an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am building a library database. I want to write a query that returns the top 5 books for each category, which means that it has to return the 5 books that are borrowed the most times for each one of the categories and the number of times they are borrowed.

The query involves the following tables:

**Book (ISBN, title,pubYear,numpages, pubName)**
**borrows (memberID, ISBN, copyNr, date_of_borrowing, date_of_return)**
**belongs_to (ISBN, categoryName)**

My approach is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM(SELECT book.title, count(bo.ISBN) as Number_of_times_book_is_taken ,be.categoryName
     FROM belong_to as be INNER JOIN borrows as bo ON be.ISBN = bo.ISBN INNER JOIN book ON bo.ISBN = book.ISBN 
     GROUP BY bo.ISBN
     ORDER BY count(bo.ISBN) DESC) AS Popular
     ORDER BY categoryName, Number_of_times_book_is_taken DESC
```

I consider this works fine if I wanted to return the titles of the books, the number of times the books are taken and the category in which they belong.

However, I want to restrict the resutls so that I get only 5 books for each of the categories. If I use `LIMIT 5` I will limit the whole result, which is not what I want. I am trying to limit each one of the categoryNames to appear max 5 times.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Or more directly, if you are building a new system, you should be using the latest version of MySQL, which supports the queries in both answers.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:  I build by database on localhost phpadmin and the version of MySql is 5.7... Is it possible to make it work in this version somehow?

Comment: . . Upgrade to 8+ and use one of the answers below.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How do I upgrade the SQL version on phpmyadmin?

Comment: . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I downloaded the latest version of MySQL with MySQL workbench...But how do I run the newest version on phpmyadmin?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Could you provide an alterantive answer that is compatible with my older MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

in mysql 8.0+ version you can use row_number()

```
with cte as
(
      SELECT book.title, count(bo.ISBN) as Number_of_times_book_is_taken ,
      be.categoryName,
      row_number() over(partition by be.categoryName order by count(bo.ISBN) desc) rn
     FROM belong_to as be INNER JOIN borrows as bo
     ON be.ISBN = bo.ISBN INNER JOIN book ON bo.ISBN = book.ISBN 
     GROUP BY be.categoryName,book.title

) select * from cte where rn<=5
```

Comment: When I try to run this SQL query I get the following error:  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte as
 (
       SELECT book.title, count(bo.ISBN) as Number_of_times_book_is_ta' at line 1` I am building the database on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @MJ13 check your mysql version it will work for >=8 version

Comment: I build by database on localhost phpadmin and the version of MySql is 5.7... Is it possible to make it work in this version somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function Row Number, Partition by Category.
Then 
select 
       * 
from 
     (Query) as Test 
Where Rownumber <= 5

See below link.

[How to return a incremental group number per group in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359749/how-to-return-a-incremental-group-number-per-group-in-sql)

Comment: I know you're only responding to the other Comment but if you just use a simple nest then it is standard.

Comment: Thanks for your response and sorry for not responding to you. My problem is that I am building the databse on phpmyadmin and the MYSQL version installed doesn't support this query since I get an error. Is there a way to fix that?